# Insert sections in a Moodle course

Tags: moodle

I am trying to create sections within a **Moodle** course using a **script** but I can not. I am using Moodle `course_create_sections_if_missing` function but can not get sections are displayed on the web but in the database they are created.

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
if($numSections >0){                   

    foreach ($sections as $nameSection) {

        $idSection = checkSections($moodle_course , $nameSection);

        if($idSection == -1){                                   

            m("crear section: ". $nameSection);

            $maxSection = getMaxSections($moodle_course );

            if($maxSection != -1){                              
                m("max section: " . $maxSection);

                $idSec = $maxSection + 1;
                course_create_sections_if_missing($moodle_course , $idSec);

                $res = updateNameSection($moodle_course , $nameSection, $idSec); 

                m("result update: " . $res);

            }else{
                m("There aren't sections for the course");
            }

        }else{
            m("section already exists: ". $nameSection);
        }   
    }
}else{
    m("No sections for the course. ");
}
```

Note: the m ( "") function is responsible for displaying the text on the console.

the function **checkSections** is this:

```
/**
 * Check if there is a section.
 *
 * @param $course id of the course.
 * @param $section name of the section
 *
 * @return id of section
 */
function checkSections($course , $section){

    global $DB;
    $id = null;

    $sql = "SELECT id FROM mdl_course_sections where course = ? and name = ? ";
    $sections = $DB->get_records_sql($sql, array($course, $section));

    foreach ( $sections as $r ) {                       
        $id = $r->id;
    }

    if(is_null($id))
        return -1;
    else
        return $id;
}
```

the function **getMaxSections** is this:

```
/**
 * Returns the id of the highest section for a course.
 *
 * @param $course id of the course.
 *
 * @return max id of section
 */
function getMaxSections($course){

    global $DB;
    $id = null;

    $sql = "SELECT max(section) as sec FROM mdl_course_sections where course = ? ";
    $sections = $DB->get_records_sql($sql, array($course));

    foreach ( $sections as $r ) {                       
        $id = $r->sec;
    }

    if(is_null($id))
        return -1;
    else
        return $id;
}
```

the function **updateNameSection** is this:

```
/**
 * Update the name of a section .
 *
 * @param $course id of the course.
 * @param $nameSection name of the section.
 * @param $idSection id of the section.
 *
 * @return result
 */
function updateNameSection($course, $nameSection , $idSection){

    global $DB;
    $id = null;

    $sql = "update mdl_course_sections set name = ? where course = ? and section = ?";
    $result = $DB->execute($sql, array($nameSection , $course, $idSection));

    return $result;
}
```

So if anyone knows how to do it or have any examples or documentation that may be useful, it would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the sections number on the table **mdl_course_format_options**

Try this:

```
$sql = "update mdl_course_format_options set value = ? where courseid = ? and name ='numsections'";
$result = $DB->execute($sql, array($numSections , $course));
```

Answer (score 0):

I try the code that @aleix suggest and it works fine for me, and this is how the code is:

```
if($numSections >0){                   

    foreach ($sections as $nameSection) {

        $idSection = checkSections($moodle_course , $nameSection);

        if($idSection == -1){                                   

            m("crear section: ". $nameSection);

            $maxSection = getMaxSections($moodle_course );

            if($maxSection != -1){                              
                m("max section: " . $maxSection);

                $idSec = $maxSection + 1;
                course_create_sections_if_missing($moodle_course , $idSec);

                $res = updateNameSection($moodle_course , $nameSection, $idSec); 


                if($res){   
                    $idSec = $idSec + 1;
                    $res2 = updateNumSectionsCourse($comunidad_moodle, $idSec);
                }        
            }else{
                m("There aren't sections for the course");
            }

        }else{
            m("section already exists: ". $nameSection);
        }   
    }
}else{
    m("No sections for the course. ");
}
```

and the function **updateNumSectionsCourse** is this:

```
/**
 * Update the number of sections for a course.
 *
 * @param $course id of the course.
 * @param $numSections number of sections.
 *
 * @return result
 */
function updateNumSectionsCourse($course, $numSections){

    global $DB;

    $sql = "update mdl_course_format_options set value = ? where courseid = ? and name ='numsections'";
    $result = $DB->execute($sql, array($numSections , $course));

    return $result;
}
```